# Аварийное завершение работы при добавлении панели

Tags: java

При первой компиляции появилась следующая ошибка:

> The selection cannot be lauched, and are no recent launche.

После её решения и повторной сборки был выдан следующий stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Container.java:490)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1091)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(JLayeredPane.java:231)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:973)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(JRootPane.java:626)
at javax.swing.JFrame.setContentPane(JFrame.java:698)
at ru.bubblesShooter.GameStart.main(GameStart.java:12)
```

Чем это может быть вызвано?

Исходный код:

```
package ru.bubblesShooter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameStart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();
        JFrame startFrame = new JFrame();
        startFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        startFrame.setContentPane(panel);
        startFrame.pack();
        startFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        startFrame.setVisible(true);
        panel.start();
    }    
}


package ru.bubblesShooter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GamePanel extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    // Fields

    public static int WIDTH = 400;
    public static int HEIGHT = 400;

    private Thread thread;

    private BufferedImage image;
    private Graphics2D g;

    private GameBack background;


    // Constructor

    public GamePanel() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();

    }

    public void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    // Methods

    @Override
    public void run() {

        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g =(Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        background = new GameBack();
        while(true) { // TODO States

            gameUpdate();
            gameRender();
            gameDraw();

            try {
                thread.sleep(33);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // TODO FPS
        }

    }

    public void gameUpdate() {
        // Background update

        background.update();
    }

    public void gameRender() {
        // Background draw

        background.draw(g);
    }

    private void gameDraw() {
        Graphics g2 = this.getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        // GC
        g2.dispose();
    }
}


package ru.bubblesShooter;

import java.awt.*;

public class GameBack {

    // Fields

    private Color color;

    // Constructor

    public GameBack() {
        color = Color.BLUE;
    }

    // Methods

    public void update() {

    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, GamePanel.WIDTH, GamePanel.HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст ошибки в общем-то всё объясняет. Вы пытаетесь добавить в контейнер нечто, являющееся окном (`java.awt.Window`), а это запрещено (полагаю, окна задуманы как контейнеры верхнего уровня). Ваш класс `GamePanel` наследуется от `JFrame`, а тот от `Window`, поэтому `GamePanel` нельзя использовать для `JFrame.setContentPane()`.

Вам нужно наследовать `GamePanel` от чего-то другого, например, от `JPanel`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Нашел ошибку, теперь все прерасно работает. Ошибка не много не втом месте, где вы говорили, но я по сути одно  и тоже. Неправильное наследование.

Comment: Плюсануть ответ не смогу, т.к. рейтинга не хвататет.

Comment: @АндрейКулик А в чём была ошибка?

Comment: я наследовал от JFrame, а надо было от JPanel, ну и там покатилось все из-за этого.

Comment: @АндрейКулик Эмм... Я вроде так в ответе и написал, а вы сказали, что ошибка не в том месте, где я указал.

Comment: Ой, не дочитал) извените, когда понял, где может быть ошибка сразу править побежал)

Comment: @АндрейКулик Понятно :) Кстати, хоть вы и не можете пока голосовать, вы можете [принять ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).